# Waiting for code to execute (already used dispatch groups)

Tags: objective-c, block, dispatch-async

Got this lengthy section of code shown below and I've hit a brick wall. Basically the code runs perfectly and does exactly what I want it to do. However, it needs to finish running all the code within this section before printing the "Finished" at the end. However adding semaphores or another dispatch group forces a breakpoint. Might be obvious, but could someone give me a bit of advice on this please?

**Note:** I cannot use that dispatch at the bottom to call another method. Remember its within a loop.

```
for (id i in arr) {
    searchByName = nil;
    if ([i containsString:@"word1"] || [i containsString:@"word2"]) {
        NSRange searchFromRange = [i rangeOfString:@"ong>"];
        NSRange searchToRange = [i rangeOfString:@"</str"];
        NSString *substring = [i substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(searchFromRange.location+searchFromRange.length, searchToRange.location-searchFromRange.location-searchFromRange.length)];
        [allergens addObject:substring];
        if ([substring isEqualToString:@"Examee"] && veg_lac_ovoSafe == TRUE) {
            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;
            vegSafe = FALSE;
        }
        else if ([substring isEqualToString:@"Example"] && veg_lac_ovoSafe == TRUE) { //USE OF HEURISTICS
            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
            vegSafe = FALSE;
        }
        else if ([substring isEqualToString:@"Exam"]) {
            pescetarianSafe = TRUE;
            vegSafe = FALSE;
            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;
            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
            veg_lac_ovoSafe = FALSE;
            pollotarianSafe = FALSE;
        }
        NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
        NSCharacterSet *numbersToRemove = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        substring = [[substring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        searchByName = [[[substring componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:numbersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""] lowercaseString];
    }
    else {
        NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
        NSCharacterSet *numbersToRemove = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        NSString *searchItem = [[i componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        searchByName = [[[searchItem componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:numbersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""] lowercaseString];
    }
    if (![searchByName isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_group_enter(_groupSearch);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [[self databaseQuery:searchByName] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
                                                      withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.value != NULL) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
                    for (int i=0; i < [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", snapshot.value] length]; i++) {
                        NSString *x  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", snapshot.value] characterAtIndex:i]];
                        NSLog(@"%@", x);
                        if ([x isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"4"]) { //Could use switch case.
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lac_ovoSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"5"]) {
                            pescetarianSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"6"]) {
                            pollotarianSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                }

                dispatch_group_leave(_groupSearch);
            }
                                                withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                dispatch_group_leave(_groupSearch);
            }];
        });
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            dispatch_group_wait(_groupSearch, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
            dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                //Hi
            });
        });
    }
}

NSLog(@"Finished");
```

Comment: I rolled back your latest updates. Instead of replacing your question with your solution (which makes the answers below useless), you should post an answer below with your final solution if you believe it will provide helpful information not already found in the existing answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your use of `dispatch_group_wait` is in the wrong place. It needs to after the `for` loop, not inside it. And you can create `queue` before the loop and reuse it as needed.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

for (id i in arr) {
    searchByName = nil;

    // Lots of other code here

    if (![searchByName isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        dispatch_group_enter(_groupSearch);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [[self databaseQuery:searchByName] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.value != NULL) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
                    for (int i=0; i < [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", snapshot.value] length]; i++) {
                        NSString *x  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", snapshot.value] characterAtIndex:i]];
                        NSLog(@"%@", x);
                        if ([x isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;

                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"4"]) { //Could use switch case.
                            vegSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lac_ovoSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_lacSafe = FALSE;
                            veg_ovoSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"5"]) {
                            pescetarianSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                        else if ([x isEqualToString:@"6"]) {
                            pollotarianSafe = FALSE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                dispatch_group_leave(_groupSearch);
            }
            withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                dispatch_group_leave(_groupSearch);
            }];

        });
    }
}

dispatch_group_wait(_groupSearch, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));

NSLog(@"Finished");
```

Comment: OP should be using `dispatch_group_notify()`, not `dispatch_group_wait()`, since he appears to want to run the completion block on the global dispatch queue.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka What completion block? There's no completion block. Using `dispatch_group_notify` is one option. So is `dispatch_group_wait`. And to whomever down voted, no need to down vote a perfectly valid answer just because you might do it another way.

Comment: Read the code in the OP. He's running `dispatch_group_wait` inside a `dispatch_async` block; he wants to run the completion code (i.e. the code after the `dispatch_group_wait`) asynchronously on the global queue. Blocking a dispatch queue by waiting on it like this is bad practice, as it ties up one of the threads in the GCD thread pool. `dispatch_group_notify` should be used instead.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka The OP is misusing the `dispatch_group_wait` inside the loop. That's why it was in the `dispatch_async` so it wouldn't block the loop. The question clearly states they want the final "finished" to print only after all of the async processing is done. My answer solves that problem.

Comment: He calls it twice though, the second time with `dispatch_sync` to make sure it runs on his high-priority dispatch queue. I think it's pretty clear that this is supposed to run on the queue, not to block the thread that called the method.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka You are speculating about that seemingly worthless call to `dispatch_sync` call with just a comment of "Hi". We have no idea what the OP is really doing with that call. The question asked one thing - how to have the code wait to call that final "Finished" print statement. My answer solves that question. All of your speculation is irrelevant to the question being asked and it's no reason to down vote a valid answer. If the question were clarified with more constraints then both of our answers could be updated to meet those currently non-existent needs.

Comment: I'll give it a try @rmaddy. And yes that's the goal. The call to dispatch sync is for each individual iteration so once the block inside it is done. I will probably remove that but has nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Comment: Your logic works and it runs most times. For some reason though it enters the dispatch group 55 times and leaves 56 times, causing the program to force itself to break? @rmaddy

Comment: I didn't change your use of enter and leave. Is it possible for both blocks to be called resulting in two calls to `dispatch_group_leave` for one call to `dispatch_group_enter`?

Comment: @BennyBoy Your updated code still uses `dispatch_group_wait` to block a dispatch queue, only to immediately use `dispatch_async` to run some code on another queue. Although this may seem to work, it is improper to block GCD threads like this. You should use `dispatch_group_notify` when the work that you need to do is to be executed on a dispatch queue. `dispatch_group_notify` will execute the block you pass to it on the queue you specify, without blocking the thread you call `dispatch_group_notify` on.

Comment: i.e. `dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{ /* do something */ });` gets you the same result as `dispatch_group_wait(group, time); dispatch_async(queue, ^{ /* do something */ });`, but does it without needlessly blocking a thread in the GCD thread pool.

Comment: @rmaddy, managed to figure it out. My solution built on from your solution works as shown above. And CharlesSrstka, I'll keep that in mind and I've already updated my code accordingly in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `dispatch_group_wait()` inside a `dispatch_async()` block, it appears you want to run the completion block asynchronously on the global dispatch queue. The proper way to do this is to use `dispatch_group_notify()` instead:

```
dispatch_group_notify(groupSearch, queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Finished")
});
```

This will run the block on the specified queue once all the blocks submitted to the group have finished, so no `dispatch_async()` or `dispatch_sync()` is needed. Additionally, waiting inside `dispatch_async()` will block a thread in the GCD pool, which is a really bad idea since there are a finite number of them. This is also something that using `dispatch_group_notify()` instead will avoid.

EDIT: The paragraph below is no longer relevant to your updated code:

<strike>Also, as the other answerer pointed out, you probably want to put the call to `dispatch_group_notify()` after the loop finishes, assuming that you want one completion block to run at the very end of your work. If what you want actually is a whole bunch of separate notifications, one for each run through the loop, then you should probably create a new group within the loop and use that instead. Using one group for the whole shebang and then setting up notifications within the loop is going to cause each notification to wait not only for the `dispatch_group_leave()` calls for that particular run through the loop, but for *all* the `dispatch_group_enter()` calls that have been made on *any* run through the loop to be balanced. So you'll get nothing until all your work is done, and then you'll suddenly spam a whole bunch of completion blocks all at once, with an accompanying thread explosion since they'll all be submitted on the global queue. This is probably not what you want.</strike>